# Few bubbles hidden behind a larger bubble in a bubble chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bubble-chart, rcharts

I am using a bubble chart to visually present my data. The problem I am facing is the bubbles with smaller area are hidden behind a larger bubble in a bubble chart in R.

```
V1  V2                          V3     V4
fl  unfair business practices   14      Y
fl  Corrections                  1      Y
fl  Product differs              1      Y
fl  refund not paid              0      Y
fl  Single premium               0      Y
fl  unfair business practices    52     N
fl  Corrections                  63     N
fl  Product differs              9      N
fl  refund not paid              2      N
fl  Single premium               2      N
mc  unfair business practices    19     Y
mc  Corrections                  0      Y
mc  Single premium               0      Y
mc  unfair business practices    36     N
mc  Corrections                  2      N
mc  Single premium               2      N

symbols(dat1$V2, dat1$V1, circles=dat1$V3)
radius <- sqrt( dat1$V3/ pi )
symbols(dat1$V2, dat1$V1, circles=radius, inches = 0.35, fg = "dark blue", bg = "red", xlab = "CASE REASON", ylab = "WORDS")
```

My problem is (say) V1 = "fl" and V2 = "unfair business practices" appears twice in my data, I am plotting 2 bubbles, but the smaller one is hidden behind the Larger bubble. I want the smaller one to be visible in my plot

Also I want to use V4 column to represent the color of the bubble. Ex: If V4 = "Y", I want the bubble to be red else I want it to be green.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you sort your data so that the smaller circles are at the end of the data.frame:

```
dat1 <- dat1[order(dat1$V3, decreasing=TRUE),]
```

(and ensure you calculate radius on the new dat1 - or replace `circles=radius` with `circles = dat1$V3/pi`) then it should help (though if a collection of small circles now completely obscures one larger one, then you're never going to be able to see all the data!)

You can just change your fg and bg constants  in the symbols call with, e.g. `bg=ifelse(dat$V4=="Y", "red", "green")`